# Erro no ambiente de desenvolvimento Flask

Tags: python, flask

Criei uma aplicação em Flask, e consigo rodar normalmente executando apenas um `flask run`, mas quando rodo, aparece que está em ambiente de produção. Quando mudo para o ambiente de desenvolvimento, com `$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"`, a aplicação roda, mas recebo um erro sempre que tento fazer uma requisição.

Aqui o meu `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

from .views.mfe import mfe
from .extensions import cors

def create_app(config_file='settings.py'):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_pyfile(config_file)

    cors.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(mfe)

    return app
```

E aqui um exemplo de uma view:

```
mfe = Blueprint('mfe', __name__, url_prefix='/cfe')

@mfe.route('/emissao', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

O erro recebido é o seguinte:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 13:38:20] "POST /cfe/emissao HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Livia\Documents\my-project\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 354, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Livia\Documents\my-project\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 342, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    raise exc_info
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 13:38:21] "GET /cfe/emissao?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 13:38:21] "GET /cfe/emissao?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 13:38:21] "GET /cfe/emissao?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2021 13:38:21] "GET /cfe/emissao?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que andei pesquisando no repositório do flask, esse parece ser um um problema na própria biblioteca mas que foi corrigido.
Um usuário abriu o um ticket em Maio:
https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4096

> Exceptions are sometimes replaced with "TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException"

traduzindo:

> Exceptions são as vezes substituídas por "TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException"

Ou seja, essa exceção que você está vendo agora talvez não seja a exceção que realmente está acontecendo no seu código, pois ela pode ter sido substituída por conta desse erro na biblioteca.

Aqui está a nota de correção que foi realizada dia 22 de junho e foi feito o merge na branch master:

> fix raising error during cli lazy loading #4169

https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4169/commits/aa6dd09c2cab5eb15a45d73b5ade24b7b4131c5a

No entanto a solução do erro só estará disponível na versão 2.0.2 do flask que ainda não foi lançada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda assim você pode fazer o download da versão mais recente do código fonte do flask com o pip. Primeiro você deve desinstalar a versão atual do flask com:
`pip uninstall flask`

depois instalar do repositório do git:

`pip install git+https://github.com/pallets/flask.git`

repare que o pip pega o código da master com todos os últimos commits. Mas se você desejar, você pode pegar apenas até o commit da correção que você precisa, que é a aa6dd09c2cab5eb15a45d73b5ade24b7b4131c5a:

para isso basta rodar o comando assim:

`pip install git+https://github.com/pallets/flask.git@aa6dd09c2cab5eb15a45d73b5ade24b7b4131c5a`

Após isso acredito que quando você rodar o flask será apresentada a exceção original.